# The ``\nabla'' symbol showed incorrectly as a black disc

Tags: latex, report, symbolic-math, tex, calculus

I am working on a report, which contains an equation involved gradient. So I need the nabla symbol to be printed out like this:

[image: The ideal nabla symbol I want]

But actually, I finally got a black disc as I try to input the nabla symbol:

[image: The actual nabla symbol as a result]

I don't know if it is the problem of my code:

```latex
$\nabla_{w}\mathcal{L}(w, b, a)$
```

As for background details, I use TeXShop4.38 on macOS 10.14.6, the packages are the following:

```latex
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{secret}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argsup}{argsup}
```

Can anyone help me target the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: fdsymbol doc states (p. 19) that `\nabla` is missing...

Answer (score 3):

You can find the root cause of such problems by creating a minimal example, i.e. the minimum amount of code that is needed to reproduce the problem. In your case that would be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
$\nabla_{w}\mathcal{L}(w, b, a)$
\end{document}
```

Indeed, the documentation for `fdsymbol` states that it does not contain a symbol for `\nabla`. One simple solution would be loading `txfonts` *after* `fdsymbol`. Alternatively, you could update to the more modern `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\nabla_{w}\mathcal{L}(w, b, a)$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Notes:

- `textcomp` is needed because both `dfdsymbol` and `newtxtext` load is with different options.
- You have to decide yourself if `fdsymbol` is still needed in this case.